# Find duplicate CSS classes with WebStorm

Tags: css, webstorm

I've tried *Inspect Code* in WebStorm but it only can find issues with Invalid Elements, Unused CSS selectors, etc. but no way to find duplicate CSS properties.

For example in my CSS

```
.reg-text {
    font-weight: 400;
}
/* and somewhere deep into the CSS this class is lurking */
.reg-text {
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

WebStorm is unable to detect that this class `reg-text` is in fact duplicated. How can this be found using WebStorm?

Comment: Stylelint can do that.  https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/no-duplicate-selectors

Comment: And Stylelint can be integrated into Webstorm to automatically highlight any issues: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/using-stylelint-code-quality-tool.html

Comment: @dmikester1 I tried stylelint just now but it detects and outputs the error as a log but it does not fix the CSS file nor create a new file with the fixed version `npx stylelint "**/merged.css" --config config.json --fix --output-file log.txt`

Comment: some things it can fix automatically, some it can't you have to fix them manually.  I'm wondering if you need to drop the `--output-file log.txt` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no way to do this currently; please vote for [WEB-74](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-74) to be notified on any progress with this feature

Comment: Wow, the issue was created 9 years ago.